# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'background-task'

Tags: python, django

Python 3.7.0, django 3.0.3, django-background-tasks 1.2.5 (Using Anaconda environment)

Trying to use `django-background-tasks` as explained here https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but as soon as I add 'background_task' to `INSTALLED_APPS`, when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'background-task'"

Answer (score 2):

My bad. The package is called "background_task" and not "background-task"

Comment: what was the fix? Even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install django-background-tasks:
`pip install django-background-tasks`

Follow [this link](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: This is the correct answer.